# IntelliJ - can't find resource, nullPointerException using getResource()

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, resources

Essentially, I'm using (or trying to use) Freemarker, which requires me to set up a folder for templates using

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(File dir);
```

I've created a folder `/htmltemplates` in `src/main/resources/htmltemplates`. The class I'm trying to access the resource from is in `src/main/java`.

However, when I try to use

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/htmltemplates");
File dir = new File(url.toString());
```

I get a nullPointerException. I've tried various combinations of ClassLoader, tried using a file instead of a directory (useless, he finds nothing), searched on StackOverflow for over an hour...
I had an almost identical setup on a previous occasion, everything worked swimmingly, but now - nothing. Attempts to work out what might be different have led to absolutely zilch.

I've been running the program through IntelliJ's build environment, also tried building a `.jar` artifact (which I'd been doing before, no problem) and then running it via console, nothing works. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: This just keeps getting stranger. I've had other people at work try it out, we've both started new IntelliJ projects simultaneously, set them up identically, and they *can't replicate my problem*. What the hell?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by switching to Maven instead of using the built-in IntelliJ artifact builder. It works, but don't ask me why, I haven't the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

your code is ok, but for the program to find the resources when started from within IntelliJ, you first have to build your project with *Build/Make project*. This build step copies the files from *src/main/resources* to to the classes output directory (*target/classes* if you have a maven project) and then the classloader is able to find them.

Comment: No, as I pointed out in my original question, I've been building a `.jar`artifact, but that doesn't work either. It should be able to find the resource folder even without this step anyway, it was in the previous project I mentioned.

Comment: I just tried it myself: running from IntelliJ works and creating a jar and running from that jar works as well. So it is not mistake in the code. Have you checked that the created jar contains the htmltemplates directory?

Comment: This solves it. Why however does IntelliJ actually not build the project automatically before trying to run it? would there be cases where that would make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set relative path not an absolute, like this `htmltemplates` without slash.

And try to add any file to `htmltemplate` folder. Because, if this folder is empty, IDE does not create folder `htmltemplate` in *target\classes* path.

Before run your application, make your project in *Build > Make Project* menu item.

Comment: @BlueTooth4269 Check my answer. I supplemented it.

Comment: Nope :( Still nothing.
I also tried printing the classpath via getting all the folder urls through `ClassLoader` and the `/htmltemplates`folder is not included

Comment: @BlueTooth4269 I tried this at my project and all works fine.

Comment: So has a colleague of mine. We even did it simultaneously, step by step. His works. Mine doesn't.
As I said, my initial attempt SHOULD have worked. It did in a previous project. Something is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, hope I can help you.
I resolved it by putting the useResource.java in the same package hierarchy as the resourceFile.txt
In the useResource.java that ask for the resourceFile.txt I just wrote the name as if they were in the same directory.

For example, I wrote this line in the useResource.java code:
        database.insertMultipleEntriesAsCSV("resourceFile.txt"));

The useResource.java was inside a directory called "database" inside the "java" directory, and the resourceFile.txt was inside a directory called "database" inside the "resources" directory.
Notice that in Project Structure I marked the "java" directory as "Test" and the "resources" directory as "Resources".

Best Regards,
Tomer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing the same problem. I solved it by using the using the Classloader of the thirdparty class containing the code above and setting it on the current thread. Something like the following:

```
- resource 
- ---- my.properties
```

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(org.your.clazz.ProblemCode.class.getClassLoader());

InputStream resourceStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.properties");
```